# Targetting DataGrid Row Header is being applied to many rows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I'm importing an excel file to a wpf DataGrid to save the data in the database.
Before importing the DataGrid to the database the user needs to check if the data is correct.
In the database there are some parameters to be compared with the data coming from the excel File. One of these parameters is Start_Import_Row whic is basically the starting point to the import i.e. everything above the starting row will not be included to the database import.
[image: The main window]

The blue arrow on the row header shows the user where the import will start and the user can change the starting point before the import, the default value is set in the database depending on the selected type in the ComboBox at the top left corner.

When the DataGrid is small everything is working as it should, but whenever the DataGrid gets a vertical scroller the blue arrow keeps getting repeated every few rows like this:
[image: The beginning of the DataGrid]

[image: The DataGrid after scrolling for a few rows]

I'm almost sure that the fail is occurring when I'm targeting the DataGrid row because as you might know, DataGrid has a Columns property but it does not have a Rows property.
I tried changing the way I'm picking the rows but I'm using this method GetRow in many other places in the application and it was the most efficient way among the things i tried and yet nothing really worked as it should.

and here is my code (I deleted any code that has nothing to do with the problem) :

```
 Private Sub OpenFileCommandExecute(obj As Object)
    Dim openFile As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    openFile.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm"
    openFile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx"
    If openFile.ShowDialog() = True Then
        Try
                ExcelToDataGrid(openFile)
                SetStartingRowArrowHeader()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Failed" + vbNewLine + ex.Message)
        Finally
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = Nothing
        End Try

    End If

End Sub

 Private Sub SetStartingRowArrowHeader()
    Dim _window = TryCast(Me.NotifyWindow, Import)
    Dim dg = _window.dgExcelDataGrid
    Dim startingRow = ExcelSheetTypeSelected.Start_Import_Row
    Dim fa = New FontAwesome.WPF.ImageAwesome()
    fa.Icon = FontAwesome.WPF.FontAwesomeIcon.ArrowCircleOutlineRight
    fa.Width = 15
    fa.Height = 15
    fa.Foreground = Brushes.Blue
    dg.GetRow(startingRow).Header = fa
    RaiseCanShiftStartingRowCommandChanged()
End Sub
```

and here is the extension method that is picking the row :

```
  <Extension()>
Public Function GetRow(ByVal grid As DataGrid, ByVal index As Integer) As DataGridRow
    Dim row As DataGridRow = CType(grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index), DataGridRow)

    If row Is Nothing Then
        grid.UpdateLayout()
        grid.ScrollIntoView(grid.Items(index))
        row = CType(grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index), DataGridRow)
    End If

    Return row
End Function
```

Comment: You have "if row Is Nothing".  The ScrollIntoView is only going to happen when row is nothing.  Is ScrollIntoView in wrong place in code?

Comment: No not really, it's used only if the convert doesn't work and that could be for not being able to find the row with that specific index so it's used to scroll to that specific index to be able to pick it and convert it to DataGridRow data type afterwards . Anyway i tested to get it out of null check just to see if I thought wrong but still not working. Thanks though.